# how to download and build libijs source?

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries, printers

as title, i need libijs source. but i can't fond after googled it.

Comment: http://www6.frugalware.org/mirrors/linux/frugalware/frugalware-testing/source/lib/ijs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build && install libijs for ARM.

```
#!/bin/sh

DESTDIR=${PWD}/_install
# 1.download source 
wget http://www6.frugalware.org/mirrors/linux/frugalware/frugalware-testing/source/lib/ijs/ijs-0.35.tar.gz  &&

# 2.
tar xvzf ijs-0.35.tar.gz && cd ijs-0.35 &&

# 3.configure
./configure --host=arm-linux --target=arm-linux --build=i686-linux CC=arm-linux-gcc CXX=arm-linux-g++ LD=arm-linux-ld RANLIB=arm-linux-ranlib AR=arm-linux-ar --enable-shared  &&

# 4.build && install
make install  DESTDIR=${DESTDIR}
```

thanks Yanshof.